# Intersection ranges (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

As example I have next arrays:

```
[100,192]
[235,280]
[129,267]
```

As intersect arrays we get:

```
[129,192]
[235,267]
```

Simple exercise for people but problem for creating algorithm that find second multidim array…

Any language, any ideas..

If somebody do not understand me:

[image]

Comment: You forget `java` tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is python implementation of intersection algorithm. Its computcomputational complexity O(n^2).

```
a = [[100,192],[235,280],[129,267]]

def get_intersections(diapasons):
    intersections = []
    for d in diapasons:
        for check in diapasons:
            if d == check:
                continue
            if d[0] >= check[0] and d[0] <= check[1]:
                right = d[1]
                if check[1] < d[1]:
                    right = check[1]
                intersections.append([d[0], right])
    return intersections

print get_intersections(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you wish to output any range that has 2 or more overlapping intervals.
So the output for `[1,5]`, `[2,4]`, `[3,3]` will be (only) `[2,4]`.

The basic idea here is to use a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Split the ranges into start- and end-points.

Sort the points.

Now iterate through the points with a counter variable initialized to 0.

If you get a start-point:

- Increase the counter.
- If the counter's value is now 2, record that point as the start-point for a range in the output.

If you get an end-point

- Decrease the counter.
- If the counter's value is 1, record that point as the end-point for a range in the output.

**Note:**

If a start-point and an end-point have the same value, you'll need to process the end-point first if the counter is 1 and the start-point first if the counter is 2 or greater, otherwise you'll end up with a 0-size range or a 0-size gap between two ranges in the output.

This should be fairly simple to do by having a set of the following structure:

```
Element
  int startCount
  int endCount
  int value
```

Then you combine all points with the same value into one such element, setting the counts appropriately.

**Running time:**

`O(n log n)`

**Example:**

Input:

```
[100, 192]
[235, 280]
[129, 267]
```

(`S` for start, `E` for end)

```
Points |   |  100  |  129  |  192  |  235  |  267  |  280  |
Type   |   | Start | Start |  End  | Start |  End  |  End  |
Count  | 0 |   1   |   2   |   1   |   2   |   1   |   0   |
Output |   |       | [129, |  192] | [235, |  267] |       |
```

Comment: @dfb The initial sort takes O(n log n) (assuming this is required), but the rest is linear.